# Simon Tatham's Portable Puzzle Collection - building new nullgame

Tags: c

I am currently trying to learn some C. From recommendations I found here on stackoverflow I hose to implement a new puzzle to Simon Tatham's Portable Puzzle Collection. I downloaded the repository and now I am struggling to correctly build a nullgame (`nullgame.c` and `nullgame.r`) of my **own name**.

I created new files (say `mygame.c` and `mygame.R`), copied all the lines from  nullgame.c and nullgame.R, replaced all necessary words (`nullgame -> mygame`) in *mygame.R*. Now, when I run *mkfiles.pl* and than *make*, I get this error message:

```
...something...
    /home/puzzles/gtk.c:362: undefined reference to `gdk_colormap_alloc_color'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:1569: recipe for target 'mygame' failed
    make: *** [mygame] Error
```

What did I do wrong? I am clearly missing something. The Developers documentation here https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/devel/writing.html#writing says I should edit Recipe, but I can't find any place to alter in this file.

Is there anyone, who can help me? I am feeling like wasting too much time on this and would like to get coding.

Comment: Alternatively I am searching for a some instructions to create blank game of new name completely same as nullgame. Readme, CHECKLST.txt and Developers documentation are not complete, or instructing enough.

Comment: This is a linker error. The linker cannot find the library with `gdk_colormap_alloc_color()`. Perhaps you need to update gtk?

Comment: Here is _[a reference](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libgdk-x11-2.0.html)_ that may help.  You probably have the library, but just did not include it in your compile command.  Linking examples _[here](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html)_.

Comment: I have the newest version of gtk. There should be no need to include it. All is done automatically by the framework. The `Makefile` is generated by a pl script. The author warns not to touch Makefiles, only to create the copies of `nullgame.c/.R` and alter only the file `Recipe`.